# react npm run build failing but run start works

Tags: reactjs, npm

my application keeps failing to create npm build, it throws the error that

```
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined        
CompileError: Begins at CSS selector input.advert:focus


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! public@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the public@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

it is kind of hard for me to debug this because I have removed all my `toLowerCase` methods , even searching project global returns 0 found and still I get this could it be modules am using or something?

my packages has

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^2.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "qrcode.react": "^1.0.0",
    "query-string": "^6.13.7",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-dnd": "^5.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.2.4",
    "react-image-crop": "^8.6.6",
    "react-image-magnify": "^2.7.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "tiny-slider-react": "^0.4.0",
    "tsutils": "^3.17.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "underscore": "^1.12.0"
```

Will appreciate help getting out of this

Comment: Have you try searching in node_modules ? I use VS code and it ignores searching that folder by default

Comment: I have but there are a tone of them but is obliviously clear I cannot go reading all the codes in every module, needed help if anyone has ever encountered such or knew which module from the one I gave could possibly be misbehaving so I could change only that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason I dont understand too, the problem is not with JavaScript but CSS,

```
input.advert:focus {
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: none;
}
```

the above CSS does not seem to allow the bundle to build, when I remove it, the compilation now goes through

maybe could explain or `:focus` is not supported maybe because `:active` has the same styles but works just fine